# Why does OnPropertyChanged not work in Code Behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inotifypropertychanged

I'm trying to simplify some code by putting the ViewModel models into the code behind and binding the DataContext as "this", but it seems to work differently, in the following example:

**Why is it when the button is clicked, the TextBlock bound to "Message" does not change, even though OnPropertyChanged("Message") is called?**

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestSimple223.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Button Content="Button" 
                Click="button1_Click" />
        <TextBlock 
            Text="{Binding Path=Message, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="Message2"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TestSimple223
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        #region ViewModelProperty: Message
        private string _message;
        public string Message
        {
            get
            {
                return _message;
            }

            set
            {
                _message = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Message");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;

            Message = "original message";
            Message2.Text = "original message2";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Message = "button was clicked, message changed";
            Message2.Text = "button was click, message2 changed";
        }

        #region INotify
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        } 
        #endregion


    }
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You haven't marked your class as being available for property change notification. Change the heading to

```
public partial class Window1 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Just because you implement the methods doesn't mean that WPF knows that a class supports change notification - you need to tell it by marking it with INotifyPropertyChanged. This way, the binding mechanism can identify your class as a potential update target.

Comment: Would he not also need to set the Data Context to itself in the xaml?
`DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`