# How to set number of items in owner-drawn listbox

Tags: c#, listbox, numbers, ownerdrawn

I've implemented the MeasureItem and DrawItem methods in my C# owner-drawn-fixed listbox.

Nothing shows up.

Out of desperation, I added three random strings to the Items collection, and THE FIRST THREE OF MY ITEMS SHOWED UP!

This tells me the listbox didn't know there were items.  Do I have to add hundreds of dummy items to the Items collection, just to see MY items??  This is dingbatty; there should be a way to TELL the listbox how many items there are -- I just can't find it!

How do you set the number of items in an owner-drawn listbox?

The code:

```
private void listVersions_MeasureItem (object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.ItemHeight = font.Height + 6;
}

private void listVersions_DrawItem (object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (entries == null)
        return;

    int i = e.Index;

    if (i < 0 || i >= entries.Count)
        return;

    e.Graphics.FillRectangle (new SolidBrush (BackColor), e.Bounds);
    VersionEntry ent = entries[i];
    Rectangle rect = e.Bounds;
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;

    g.DrawString (i.ToString () + "  " + ent.name, font, Brushes.Black, rect.Location);
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Tack this on to your post.. it would look a lot better.  Also, are you perhaps looking for [OnPropertyChanged?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034840/handling-onpropertychanged)

Comment: I don't see how OnPropertyChanged would help; nothing changes: I just want to display a list.

Comment: "entries" is a list that contains the items to draw.  The whole purpose of the owner-drawn listbox is to display entries.  And when I add dummy items to the Items collection, the entries items are correctly drawn.  IT LOOKS LIKE THE ONLY PROBLEM IS TELLING THE LISTBOX HOW MANY ITEMS THERE ARE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making the DataSource of your ListBox your entries collection:

```
listVersions.DataSource = entries
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

They (allegedly) have an LB_SETCOUNT message that can be sent to a list box.

Microsoft really should provide a SetCount () method in CListBox, but they often leave out methods you need for non-toy applications.  Grrr...